# Strange behavior of min-width in IE8

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a simple requirement ;
Apply desktop.css for larger screen sizes AND
Apply iPad.css for somewhat smaller screen sizes

Now I want to use CSS Media Queries for these.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width: 768px)" href="css\desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="css\ipad.css">
```

Now I have read that older IE does not have support for min-width. But there is a strange kind of support that I see in IE8
i.e IE8 recognizes  min-width as a property, but not as a media query.

So

> `#example{*min-width:100px;}`

works fine in IE8

But this does not

```
@media only screen and (min-width:100px)
```

I have already tried the following for IE

```
<!--[if IE ]><link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css\desktop.css"><![endif]-->
```

But I want to apply IE desktop css at a particular min-width only and NOT always..

Is there a JS workaround for this like;

```
<!--[if IE AND min-width:100px]><link rel...
```

Please let me know how I can apply 2 set of CSS in IE.

Comment: Side-note: I see a flaw here. If actual width is exactly 768 pixels, both CSS sheets would be used.  [Width refers to viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#width).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Media queries are only supported by IE9+.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#media)
You can use a polyfill like [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) for IE6-8 compatibility.

Comment: Thx...I am facing some access denied issues with Respond.js...I just want to test on local disk..can u help me fix the same..

Comment: Hmm since respond.js makes ajax requests to grab and parse stylesheets you can't test it locally without a web server. Try [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) its very easy to install and use.

Comment: Actually I am looking at something which would not require any additional server install....Is there some other way to install this ? Also if not, I do use Apache for server-side testing..If you could just briefly add the steps to make it work in Apache..

Comment: It will work with whatever web server you got just not without one. If you're using Apache to access your html page then it should be working fine. What error do you get exactly?

Comment: Actually I did try running on the server bcoz I did not follow the instructions like where to upload the JS, where to upload the proxy gif, etc...So if you could let me know in simpler terms coz i am mainly from ui background and not from server-side..